# Update json file by curl command

Tags: python, json, curl

I'm trying to make an app which writes and make updates in a `json` file by accepting data from the `curl` utility. Right now my code looks like:

```
import os
import flask import Flask, url_for, json, request, jsonify

database = "./meeting_rooms.json"

@app.route('/book_room', methods = ['POST'])
def api_book_room():
if request.headers['Content-Type'] == 'application/json':
 if os.stat(database).st_size == 0:
   with open(database, 'w') as f:
     data = request.get_json()
     json.dump (data, f, indent=4)
     return "OK\n", 200
 else:
  with open(database,'r+') as f:
     data = json.load(f)
     data.update(request.get_json())
     json.dump(data, f, indent=4)
     return "OK\n", 200
```

`curl` usage:

```
curl -H "Content-type: application/json" -X POST http://127.0.0.1:5000/book_room -d '{"4":{"room":"602","date":"2 days ago","booked_by":"HR"}} '
```

But all I got is

```
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 2 column 1 (char 1)**. json file is empty.
```

What I'm doing wrong considering I have no real-world `python` experience?

Comment: Okay, but the data from curl must be written to the json file and in my case it doesn't happening.

Comment: If the JSONDecodeError appears in the line "data = json.load(F)" it seems that your meeting_rooms.json has no content

Comment: Yes, the file is empty and I've added 'if else' condition to check its size. But it doesn't help, I'm getting the same error.

Comment: use `os.path.exists(database)` instead of `os.stat(database).st_size`

Comment: I think there is an empty line in your file so `st_size != 0` but json decode see an empty file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A solution that catch error at json decode time. it check file existence and file typo.

```
import os
from flask import Flask, url_for, json, request, jsonify
from path import Path

app = Flask(__name__)

database = "./meeting_rooms.json"

@app.route('/book_room', methods = ['POST'])
def api_book_room():
  if request.headers['Content-Type'] == 'application/json':
    try:
      tmp = json.load(open(database, 'r'))
    except (ValueError, FileNotFoundError):
      # FileNotFoundError: raised if file don't exist
      # ValueError: raised if json is not able to decode
      tmp = {}


    for k, v in request.get_json().items():
      tmp[k] = v

    with open(database,'w') as f:
      json.dump(tmp, f, indent=4)

    return "OK\n", 200

  return "FAIL\n", 200

app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=8080, debug=True)
```

Edit: Update keys instead of append it.

Comment: Is that possible to write into the json file to look like this?
{
 "1": {
  "room": "valore",
  "date": "valore"
 },
 "2": {
  "room": "valore",
                "date": "valore"
 },
 "3": {
  "id": "valore",
                 date": "valore"
 }
}

Comment: Thanks again! I'd appreciate, if you can point me on topics which allows to produce such code.